# Simple char driver confusion

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

So I have been leaning device drivers in linux and saw various examples of how to create one. The most common steps were,

1. create file operations
2. create major and minor numbers
3. create a struct cdev, that will be associated later with this fops
4. create a node either using a mknod or using sysfs, like class_create and device_create.

I have a confusion, that if I don't create cdev, and just register my driver, then only create a node in sysfs, I am able to use that node with any c program. Why I should create a struct cdev in this case?

E.G. a simple init function from this place, https://sysplay.in/blog/tag/character-device-files/

```
static int __init ofcd_init(void) /* Constructor */
{
    int ret;
    struct device *dev_ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Namaskar: ofcd registered");
    if ((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, "Shweta")) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    if (IS_ERR(cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")))
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(cl);
    }
    if (IS_ERR(dev_ret = device_create(cl, NULL, first, NULL, "mynull")))
    {
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(dev_ret);
    }

    cdev_init(&c_dev, &pugs_fops);//here I am confused. Why do it? what will happen if I don't do this, as I can use my driver still.
    if ((ret = cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1)) < 0)
    {
        device_destroy(cl, first);
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would the system know to call your file operation functions if you neither create the `cdev` yourself, nor call `register_chrdev()` (or `__register_chrdev()`)?

Comment: I am not creating cdev only. I just register. I am already creating nodes using udev facilty. So I can call my driver functions

Comment: Sure you can create device nodes without a cdev, but if nothing is setting the fops, you'll just get an `ENXIO` error when you try to open the device file.